# Java - Вывести на экран аргументы командной строки в for-loop

Tags: java, циклы, командная-строка

Надо вывести на экран аргументы командной строки в цикле for.

В чем моя ошибка?
И как правильнее всего реализовать данную задачу?

```
package com.example.proverka;

class proverka {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
            System.out.println(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы их задаете при запуске, чтобы они там были?

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно какие именно аргументы следует задать и каким образом

Comment: (я по глупости своей отклонил правку, прошу прощения) и этот код у меня таки работает и аргументы выводит. @Григорий вы не знаете что такое командная строка, не умеете запускать java-программы через командную строку или в чём у вас проблема?

Comment: Код верный. Скорее всего автор не знает, как указать эти самые параметры. @Григорий эти параметры указываются в командной строке непосредственно после вызываемой команды, а в среде разработки вам следует отредкатировать конфигурацию запуска. В Idea это диалог Run/Debug Configurations -> поле Program arguments